# 3-card hand same suit containing cards of decreasing consecutive ranks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Question:
Note: Your answer must be a computed number rounded to 4 digits after the decimal point.

What is the probability of drawing a 3-card hand (from a 52-card deck) containing cards of decreasing consecutive ranks, where all cards are of the same suit? For example, (5♥, 4♥, 3♥), (J♦, 10♦, 9♦), but not (3♠, 2♠, A♠). Use bijection to compute a number of favorable outcomes.

My Solution:

Since there are 52 cards in the deck, then there are S = 52C3 = 22,100 possible combinations of three-card hands possible. 
Drawing a 3-card hand (from a 52-card deck) containing cards of decreasing consecutive ranks, where all cards are of the same suit.
There are 11 possible sequences:
E = {(AKQ), (KQJ), (QJ10), (J109), (1098), (987), (876), (765), (654), (543), (432)} ***(32A) is not counted.
There are 3! ways to draw for each subset of E.
For example: (AKQ) = AKQ, AQK, KAQ, KQA, QAK, QKA
Since there are 4 suits, then the number of 3-card straight flushes possible is just 11 * 6 * 4 = 246.
⇒ Pr[E] = |E| / |S| = 246/22100 = 0.0119.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but not quite.  In the denominator, you have $\binom{52}{3}$, which means that you are not taking the order in which the cards are dealt into account, but just considering the combinations of $3$ cards; the number of distinct $3$-card hands.  So you shouldn't take order into account in the nuerator either.  You should not have multiplied by $6$.  The answer is $$\frac {4\cdot11}{\binom{52}3}$$